# AWS Cognito Push Sync with Ionic

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, ionic2, amazon-cognito

Is there a plugin to use AWS Cognito Push Sync with Ionic Framework for a mobile app?

The usecase is to update sync store datasets from mobile backend and then to notify to the mobile app running in the background so that the data is available for processing in the mobile app.

Comment: No, push sync is not supported for JavaScript/TypeScript.

Comment: Are there any plugins available?